# отступы в тексте

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такие отступы вначале каждой строки? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

````
  ```<td class="txt" colspan="2" height="420">
      <p style="text-indent: 40px">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br />
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse <br />
        sed libero vel turpis tristique mattis<br />
        tempor ut risus. Nullam eleifend<br />
        imperdiet urna, a scelerisque metus<br />
        mattis nec. Nulla velit augue, rhoncus <br />
        vel nisl in, ullamcorper varius tellus. <br />
        Proin elementum nulla mauris, at <br />
        pellentesque eros volutpat at.
      </p>```
````

Comment: какие "такие"?.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{text-indent: 40px;}
```

```html
<p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br />
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse <br />
        sed libero vel turpis tristique mattis<br />
        tempor ut risus. Nullam eleifend<br />
        imperdiet urna, a scelerisque metus<br />
        mattis nec. Nulla velit augue, rhoncus <br />
        vel nisl in, ullamcorper varius tellus. <br />
        Proin elementum nulla mauris, at <br />
        pellentesque eros volutpat at.
      </p>
```

Comment: Я так и сделал, только text indent добавляет отступ первой строке, а как сделать так, чтобы у каждой строки был отступ, как на моей картинке?

Comment: Каждую новую строку оборачивайте в <p>

Comment: А это не поможет? `.main {
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #f8d5d9;
}

.main p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 40px;
}

.main p:first-child {
  margin-top: 270px;
}

.main p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 270px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Разве у вас здесь на картинке отступы у каждой строки? По-моему, весь текст выравнен по центру, а к первой строке добавлен отступ.

```css
p {
  max-width: 300px;
  text-indent: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
  consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse <br>
  sed libero vel turpis tristique mattis<br>
  tempor ut risus. Nullam eleifend<br>
  imperdiet urna, a scelerisque metus<br>
  mattis nec. Nulla velit augue, rhoncus <br>
  vel nisl in, ullamcorper varius tellus. <br>
  Proin elementum nulla mauris, at <br>
  pellentesque eros volutpat at.
</p>
```

Comment: В моём коде отступ только на первой строке. А надо было сделать, как на примере (картинка). Но, я уже разобрался и решил при помощи margin